# How to run a sudo privilege command on start up in OSX

Tags: macos, sudo, init

I have a python script which I'd like to run every time my machine boots. It requires sudo however. What's a simple solution to make my python script with sudo on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-privileged startup scripts simply add your single line command to `/etc/rc.local` for commands that require `sudo` add it to `/etc/rc.common`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `launchd`.

> launchd -- System wide and per-user daemon/agent manager

Add your property list file to the `/Library/LaunchDaemons` directory.

Have a look at [Technical Note TN2083 Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html)